# Output of ns3 script where evalvid server is sending packets to client over 802.11

Tags: server, udp, video-streaming, ns-3, wifi

evalvid server is sending packets to evalvid client over 802.11 link. I have two questions:

1. When evalvid server is sending packets, output is like this:

   > > EvalvidServer: Send packet at 1.10406s id: 1 udp 1460 to 192.168.0.1
   > >     EvalvidServer: Send packet at 1.10406s id: 2 udp 1460 to 192.168.0.1
   > >     EvalvidServer: Send packet at 1.10406s id: 3 udp 1460 to 192.168.0.1
   > >     EvalvidServer: Send packet at 1.10406s id: 4 udp 1460 to 192.168.0.1
   > >     EvalvidServer: Send packet at 1.10406s id: 5 udp 1460 to 192.168.0.1
   > >     EvalvidServer: Send packet at 1.10406s id: 6 udp 1460 to 192.168.0.1
   > >     ... to id: 64
   > >     EvalvidClient: Received packet at 1.11958s   id: 1   udp 1460
   > >     EvalvidClient: Received packet at 1.13261s   id: 2   udp 1460
   > >     EvalvidClient: Received packet at 1.14567s   id: 3   udp 1460
   > >     EvalvidClient: Received packet at 1.15866s   id: 65  udp 1460

What happened with packets id:4-64? Are they dropped? Where? In ascii script there was no information about sending this packets?

2. Why there is retransmission when using evalvid server or just UDP in 802.11:

   > > EvalvidClient: Received packet at 1.32891s   id: 91  udp 1460
   > >     drop packet because signal power too Small (3.15207e-14<2.51189e-13)
   > >     EvalvidClient: Received packet at 1.33504s   id: 92  udp 1460

Packet is dropped, retransmission is done, so there was no loss. UDP flow is without retransmission.

Thank you